Python code of plot of Fisher KPP equation
I have the following system: $x'=y$, $y'=-y+x^2-x$ and I tried using Python code to display the phase portrait along with the stable manifold (point(1,0) for the provided system of differential equations. I got this diagram:

I want to get something like that for the stable manifold (whole blue line, but with shaded areas). I want:


Where's your code?

May be this will get you started.
Given this system
\begin{align*}
      x'(t) &= F(x,y)\\
      y'(t) &= G(x,y)
\end{align*}
The phase plot is drawn using the command
 StreamPlot[{f, g}, {x, from, to}, {y, from, to}]

A specific path via a point can be added using the option StreamPoints
Code
f     = y
g     = -y + x^2 - x
s     = StreamPoints -> {{{{0, 1}, Blue}, Automatic}}
style = {StreamColorFunction -> None, StreamStyle -> Gray}
ep    = Epilog -> {Red, PointSize -> .03, Point[{0, 1}]};

StreamPlot[{f, g}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
           Evaluate@s,      
           Evaluate@style, 
           Evaluate@ep]



NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -y[t] + x[t]^2 - x[t], 
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1/10000}, {x, y}, {t, -7, 15}];
NDSolveValue[{x'[t] == y[t], y'[t] == -y[t] + x[t]^2 - x[t], 
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1/10000}, {x, y}, {t, -7, 25}];
Show[StreamPlot[{y, -y + x^2 - x}, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
  StreamColorFunction -> None], 
 ParametricPlot[{#[t] & /@ %, #[t] & /@ %%}, {t, -7, 25}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]]




Such a singular point is called a saddle.
